# Fetch div format from html layout text using div id in ios

Tags: iphone, html, objective-c, ios

Example:

```
 <html>
        <body>

         <div id="content" style="background-color:#EEEEEE;height:200px;width:400px;float:left;">
        Content goes here</div>

        </body>
        </html>
```

i am having html text(above) in nsstring ,

i need to fetch html tag/ div using div id  ;
example:

```
<div id="content" style="background-color:#EEEEEE;height:200px;width:400px;float:left;">
    Content goes here
    </div>
```

nsstring *strDiveFormat = "code required";

nsslog(@"Div Format: %@",strDiveFormat);

this should print :

```
<div id="content" style="background-color:#EEEEEE;height:200px;width:400px;float:left;">
    Content goes here
</div>
```

Comment: [How to Parse HTML on iOS](http://www.raywenderlich.com/14172/how-to-parse-html-on-ios)

Comment: I would try the tutorial provided by `esqew` as html document is not always a valid XML document.